# Error 405 with 'PUT' on nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm testing my API and both GET and POST methods are fine, but when I try PUT or DELETE it gives me the 405 error message. Im using PHP 7.3 Mysql nginx 1.25.3 on docker and testing with postman

I've already tried to explicit allow the methods in the .conf file with limit_except and dav_methods, and checked the installation arguments for http_dav_module

```
server {
    index index.html index.php;
    server_name docker.localhost;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access`.log;
    root /www;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        allow all;
        satisfy any;
        limit_except GET POST PUT DELETE {
            deny all;
        }
        dav_methods  PUT DELETE;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

and here's my POST handler on php

```
case 'PUT':
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

        // Check if required fields are present in the request
        if (!isset($data['email'], $data['pwrd'], $data['username'], $data['surname'], $data['nickname'])) {
            http_response_code(400); // Bad Request
            echo json_encode(['error' => 'Incomplete data provided']);
            exit;
        }

        // Extract data from the request
        $email = $data['email'];
        $password = $data['pwrd'];
        $username = $data['username'];
        $surname = $data['surname'];
        $nickname = $data['nickname'];

        // Prepare and execute a database query to update the user by email
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE main SET pwrd=?, username=?, surname=?, nickname=? WHERE email=?');
        $stmt->execute([$password, $username, $surname, $nickname, $email]);

        // Check if any rows were affected
        $rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();
        if ($rowCount > 0) {
            echo json_encode(['message' => 'User updated successfully']);
        } else {
            http_response_code(404); // Not Found
            echo json_encode(['error' => 'User not found']);
        }
    break;
```

Comment: I could not see anykind research done you hVe done so far, which is a requirement for this site. I found [a similar situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912270/how-do-i-allow-a-put-file-request-on-nginx-server) on stackoverflow.com - have you tried it?

Comment: yes, as I described in the second paragraph, I already checked my installment arguments for dav_module and explicit allowed the method in the nginx arguments (line 18)

Comment: I also have found another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154875/right-way-to-enable-requests-with-method-delete-in-nginx/) which might be helpful